# Top nav in foundation zurb - showing the main menu even when on mobile

Tags: zurb-foundation

When the user is on the mobile, I would like the menu to appear as well, and not be hidden. But no matter how I tweak the show-on-small options, it does not show up.

How it currently appears on a small screen

[image]

How I would like it to appear. (with the menu icon)

[image]

I would make sure that it is short enough such that it fits, but I am rather confused about how to make it work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't suppose you could post the markup you used to get what you have above? I can't get that to work using foundation 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SASS, open the **_top-bar.scss** file, find the `$topbar-breakpoint` variable, and set the pixel value to `1px`. This will make the breakpoint that causes the **foundation.topbar.js** to toggle to the mobile style too small to occur.

If you are using regular css files, search for the `.top-bar-js-breakpoint` style and change the `width` to `1px` there.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to chrisjsherm's answer, I ended up doing this. In the default app.scss file, right after the settings file is imported, override the $topbar-breakpoint variable.

```
// Global Foundation Settings
@import "settings";

// Override settings for this project only
$topbar-breakpoint: 1px;
```